# How to clean database table from garbage data after it is populated with a data from excel file?

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I have a package that dumps the data from `.xls` file into some kind of staging table.
Then I need to insert this data into a main table.

I'm looking for the way to write a sql code that would get rid off garbage data from the staging table.

This is an example of `xls` file

[image]

When executing my package, my staging table looks like this:

[image]

After that, I run the following code to delete the garbage data from the statging table:

`delete from StagingTable where Data IS NULL and DATA = 'Date'`

That takes care of garbage removal for that particular case.

But what if the data comes in so, the `xls` columns names are different, then my `delete` statement simply will not work

Is there a work around this problem?

Comment: What makes a particular row in the table garbage? In this case it's a `NULL` date, but in general how do you define what is garbage?

Comment: If the `excel` file contains `Date` columns and get imported into a database table, then column `Data` in that table will have a garbage row with `Date` value in that. I'm just thinking about a general way of identifying what is a garbage record.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer. That will work if the first column of a staging table has a date value:

`select * from StatgingTable where ISDATE(Date) = 1`

This will return:

[image]

Comment: The TRY_PARSE did not work for your version of SQL which was not specified.

Comment: @gene: what about the NULL values? image is not visible

Comment: @chandran When package dumps data from `xls` file into a staging table, NULLs are placed in the place of image.

Comment: I can see that it listed the complete rows to be deleted rt?

Comment: Basically, the query that I provided as a solution, should be revised as `delete from StagingTable where ISDATE(Date) = 0`. This way it will delete all the unnecessary(garbage) data